# How should I use modules in redux app?

Tags: node.js, architecture, redux

I'm new to Redux and trying to make a server-side Redux app using node.js.

All examples I found was tiny monolitic apps or client-side react examples.
But in my case I want to use different interchangeable modules in order to making application less coupled.

So, I need several data streams, which expose same interface to the rest of application but differ internally.

Some of them are static straightforward adapters as an http-server, which reads data from incoming http-post messages,
and some are interactive, such as console interface, which parses user input interactively in a conversation manner.

So I want to be able to exchange components without having to touch every place I use this components. But interactive ones need some local state for tracking user interactions and so on.

Should I store such states in global redux store or a little bit of local states is possible? And why?

Also do I need to emit Actions every time I need to do something module-specific stuff? Let's say when an http-request came and I would need to save it in cache. Should I emit

```
{ type: 'HTTP_STREAM_CACHE', data: '...' }
```

to the reducer or just encapsulate this kind of things into my module?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question, but I think the crux of your question is more about a Dependency Injection system instead of Redux specific. If you want different modules in different scenarios your best bet is some sort of DI pattern.  As for dispatching actions, YES, you should dispatch an action whenever you want to update the global state (via your reducers) it's in fact the only way in Redux.

Comment: May be so. What is proper way to combine dependency injection with functional nature of Redux? If we think in terms of Redux, injected service is a component of state.